# Any alternatives for float: left?

Tags: html, css

I have a blue table that uses float: left and a yellow button that is attached to this table and also uses float: left.

The button is used to add columns to the table. But when I add so many columns that the table reaches the edge of the window - the whole layout breaks and the button jumps down:

[image]

Can it be done that instead of jumping down the button stays where it is and a horizontal scrollbar appear?

The blue table is placed inside div container called canvas. Then I use:

```
.canvas {
  float: left;
}
```

and align left yellow button:

```
.addColumn {
   float: left;
}
```

Here is my [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/xwtepfdw/1/). Forget to paste it, sorry!

Any ideas how it can stop button from leaving its place when the whole structure reaches the edge of the window?

Comment: Use flexbox or grid

Comment: i think the parent element of .canvas class and adColumn has a fixed width set which is causing the add button to get pushed to next line - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oddyvo

Comment: @G-Cyr, sorry, I forget to paste the link to my working demo( it is in the main post now.

Comment: @G-Cyr, if you have an opportunity, could you please take a look at my demo? Maybe you will have an idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: @NagaSaiA, parent element of .canvas is body. I tried applying to body
  white-space: nowrap; as well as overflow-x: auto but it did not help...

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the markup, wrap the whole construct into another element, put the table *and* buttons inside that element, and use absolute positioning.

This solution should be used if you absolutely need old browser support. Check below for another snippet with a more modern and versatile method.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  
  /* for demonstration purposes */
  background: red;
}

.wrapper table {
  /* for demonstration purposes */
  background: lime;
}

.wrapper button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  /* for demonstration purposes */
  padding: 0;
}

.add-column {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.add-row {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 

<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="add-column">+</button>
  <button class="add-row">+</button>
</div>

after content content content content content content content content content content content content
```

Or if you prefer a more modern approach, you can use the CSS Grid Layout module, which doesn't require hardcoding button sizes and paddings:

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "table column"
    "row   .     ";
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: start;
  
  /* for demonstration purposes */
  background: red;
}

.wrapper table {
  grid-area: table;
  
  /* for demonstration purposes */
  background: lime;
}

.add-column {
  grid-area: column;
}

.add-row {
  grid-area: row;
}
```

```html
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content

<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="add-column">+</button>
  <button class="add-row">+</button>
</div>

after content content content content content content content content content content content content
```

I would recommend using the grid method over the absolute positioning one since in the later you would have to hardcode the width and height of the buttons, and guarantee the padding is the same.

With the grid, it's much cleaner and responsive.

Of course, if you [absolutely need 100% browser support](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), then you should prefer the `position` technique, and accept or circumvent its limitations.

Comment: @Krotlan, thank you very much for such a detailed help! May I ask you to take a look at my demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/xwtepfdw/1/ I can see that you use a different approach to the layout, but is it possible to solve the described problem with the layout that I made?

Comment: @mayua I don't think it would be possible with that layout, without using a wrapper element. But if you do, you can definitely extend the Grid concept to add another row and column before the table, and put your delete buttons there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
display:flex;
```

in your container div. This will resolve the issue and doesnt needs the the float:left property.

Also try to look into `flex-flow , align and justify items` for more combinations.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. When I apply flex - columns are added instead of rows and vice versa. Other options break the layout.

Comment: @mayua - after seeing the code I saw that using grid here will be a little confusing for you . In this case consider using a max-width for canvas

if you give 

  <div class="canvas" style="max-width:calc(100% - 20%)">

then the canvas doesnt push the plus button of yours. Do let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, but unfortunately, it simply squeezes the table in the limited space by making the cells smaller. What I want to make is to make the table enlarging by adding a scrollbar to the window when the table reaches the edge of the window.